# AWS - Elastic Beanstalk CLI - how to list/change profiles

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I have two AWS accounts, one for personal, one for work-related projects. I've previously created and deployed to my personal AWS account.

I want to create a work-related app on the work AWS account. I signed in with those credentials, and created a new application from within the console.

Then, in my work project folder, I `eb init` and `eb create`/`deploy` the work app. When I did `eb create`, it was asking to set up a an environment different than the one I had created in AWS. After creating it, I found that a new project had be created within my personal AWS account.

I was told I have to change profiles doing `eb --profile` but am not sure of my profile names. How can I list and change my profile from my personal to my work profile?

---

EDIT:

I was given an access key ID. I tried `eb --profile MYKEYID`. No message was displayed when I did this. I'm not sure which profile I'm on.

Comment: It could be a case of the AWS CLI's configuration rather than being specific to Elastic Beanstalk. You could try specifying your access keys etc inline with your commands - [this might help](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html)

Comment: @scrowler see above edit

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The EB CLI and the AWS CLI share the same credentials. 
They are stored in either `~/.aws/config` or `~/.aws/credentials`.

You can list them using

```
aws configure list
```

Once you know what profile you want to use, you can set it permanently for that project by running

```
eb init --profile ProfileName
```

in the project directory.

You can see what settings the EB CLI has for your project by looking at the `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml` file.

Comment: How do I deploy the same App to a different EB instance on the same profile? I used `eb list` but my newly created EB instance doesn't show

Comment: @Growler EB manages the instances for you. You shouldnt need to deploy apps to instances directly. Basicaly, by deploying an app, EB creates an instances for you. You can scale up your number of instances using `eb scale`

Comment: In my case, eb init --profile myProfile doesn't work. It continues to asking for aws-access-id saying that "You have not yet set up your credentials or your credentials are incorrect.". However if I run, e.g., aws s3 ls --profile myProfile it works. Any ideas?